# Equivalent of PROC POWER SAMPLEFREQ in R

Tags: r, sample-size

I want to do the power calculation (Equivalence test: 2-sided Binomial Proportion) in R. I have found the similar code in SAS (Displayed below for your reference).

```
proc power;

onesamplefreq test = equiv_exact
alpha = 0.05
proportion = 0.30
lower = 0.2
upper = 0.4
ntotal = 500
power = .;
run;
```

Can anybody help me by providing the example code in R for the similar calculation ?

Comment: for Equivalence test how can one provide the bounds (lower and upper of the Proportion ) in R ?